# MATLAB Unwanted conversion from double to int32 after indexing

Tags: matlab, types, int, double

I have this code to load data from text file, four columns - string, 3 integer columns and decimal number.

```
fileID = fopen(Files(j,1).name);
formatSpec = '%*s %d %d %d %f';    
data = zeros(0, 4, 'double');
k = 0;
while ~feof(fileID)
    k = k+1;
    temp = textscan(fileID,formatSpec,10,'HeaderLines',1);        
    data = [data; [ temp{:} ] ] ;        
end
fclose(fileID);
```

In a temp variable, the last column is saved as decimal number, however, the command
    data = [data; [ temp{:} ] ]

has as consequence its rounding and I get 0 or 1 in last column.

**I am asking why is that?**

temp looks like (1x4 cell):

```
[5248000;5248100;....]  [5248100;5248200;....]
[111;95;....]   [0,600000000000000;0,570000000000000;....]
```

data then looks like (1x4 matrix):

```
5248000 5248100 111 1
5248100 5248200 95  1
```

**EDIT:**
Retesting (recreation of the same variable, just copied numbers from variable editor)

```
temp=cell(1,4);
temp{1}=[0;100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900];
temp{2}=[100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900;1000];
temp{3}=[143;155;150;128;121;122;137;145;145;126];
temp{4}=[0.340000000000000;0.450000000000000;0.370000000000000;...
0.570000000000000;0.570000000000000;0.580000000000000;...
0.590000000000000;0.500000000000000;0.460000000000000;0.480000000000000];
tempx=[temp{:}]
```

This makes it correctly! The last columnd is decimal.

But why it doesn't work on "real" data from textscan function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider reading everything as floating point values:

change

```
formatSpec = '%*s %d %d %d %f';
```

to

```
formatSpec = '%*s %f %f %f %f';
```

If works in your EDIT because your variables are already of type `double`.

Answer (score 2):

Concatenating `double` and `int` data casts to the `int` type. For example:

```
>> [pi; int16(5)]
ans =
  2×1 int16 column vector
   3
   5
```

To avoid that, you can cast to `double` before concatenating. So in your case use something like the following to convert each cell's content to `double`(thanks to [@CrisLuengo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7328782/cris-luengo) for a correction):

```
[ data; cellfun(@double, temp, 'uniformoutput', true) ]
```

Comment: Thanks. I shoudl mentioned what I have already tried and this does not work. ans=double([temp{:}]) makes the same and converts it either.

Comment: Post a minimal example in your question then. That is,  define `temp` or provide a small file that reproduces the problem

Comment: temp=cell(1,2)
temp{1}=[1;1;1];temp{2}=[0.1;0.1;0.1];
tempx=[temp{:}]
It works here. Then, it must be problem in source, the original temp is here: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ah7xah3UhCitjsIqRnNFUreqOwUbtg

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks! Edited

Comment: Thank you for help, even I have used the latter solution (taking all as floating points).